# Showing decimal point in java

Tags: java

```
int a = 91000;
int b = Math.pow(100,2);
float ans = (float) a/b;
ans=9.1
```

I want  the output correct to 6 digits after decimal point , i.e

```
ans =9.100000
```

How can i do this in java?

Comment: Don't use `float` if you are concerned about precision.  `double` is half a trillion times more accurate.  Also don't use Math.pow for simple operations like squaring, it is expensive and relatively inaccurate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the printf method:

```
System.out.printf("%.6f", val);
```

The %.6f syntax tells Java to return your variable in a floating point number with 6 decimal places

Answer (score 1):

You ca use `DecimanlFormat`:

```
ans=9.1
System.out.println(new DecimalFormat("#0.000000").format(ans));
```

**Output :**

```
9.100000
```

For more on `DecimalFormat` visit [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) link.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to convert float to a string, after the dot you provide number of decimal digits you want to have:
`String.format("%.6f", ans)`

Have a look at documentation, for more formats: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `double` and [formatted output](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax). Something like,

```
int a = 91000;
double b = Math.pow((double) 100, 2);
double ans = a / b;
System.out.printf("%.6f%n", ans);
```

Output is

```
9.100000
```

Comment: You don't need to cast `100` to `double` here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use String.format to define the output you like, e.g.

```
String.format("Range = %.6f", range)
```

to show 6 decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to write something like

```
int a = 91000
System.out.println(a / 1e4); // there is only 4 decimal places possible
```

Or to force it to 6 digits of precision

```
System.out.printf("%,6f%n", a / 1e4);
```